# Setting Button action from XML

Tags: ios

I have buttons who's action function changes based on a certain configuration XML. I'm looking to change the button action based on the XML.

Example, I will parse this XML node and finally should be able to set the target as `doLoginSecure` for the button `loginButton`. The `doLoginSecure` method action be already defined in the iOS code.

`<button name="loginButton" target="doLoginSecure">`

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[someButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(@"yourMethod") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

replace yourMethod string with XML value

Comment: yes, but your question was about target and NOT about action right?

Comment: It was about action. I said `target` since the method doing it is `addTarget:action:forControlEvent:`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest,

Instead of assigning target to button as per xml why not you write one function which will be assigned to that button and in that use switch case which will be execute as per the xml response. 
Let say, you have loginbutton, so from xml you will be getting two function like fun1 or fun2.

Assign fun fucntion at start to loginbutton.

While parsing xml response set sone variable as 1 or 2 depending on the fucntion
say if fucntionname it fun1 then it is 1 and if it is fun2 then 2.

Now in fun,

```
-(void)fun:(int)icheck
{
   switch(iCheck)
{
   case 1:fun1();
          break;
case 2:fun2();
          break;
//......and like this
}
}
```

Comment: This would be an approach but I really need to change the action because of the requirement. Thanks anyways